# GMFBridge usage in DirectShow

Tags: directshow, directshow.net

`enter code here`I have to stop and start *Video Renderer Filter* dynamically . That is not possible with "normal" Direct Show Architecture without creating new graph. But with GMFBridge  it seems it is possible.

But i can not figure out how to use it.( yes i read the paper at http://www.gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge/index.htm )

My Graph is:

```
SourceFilter ---> MyCustomTransformFilter ---> Video Rendrer Filter
```

So GMFBridge fits where?

```
i) I can devide my graph two pieces 
       [ Source Filter + MyCustomFilter ] + Video Rendere


ii) Then how to add my filters to graph, and stop start Video Rendrere without 
affecting the rest of my grapg using GMFBridge?
```

Update:

Thanks Wimmel

I just confused... Let me clear what i understand

**i) I have single graph at first**

```
 (SingleGraph) SourceFilter ---> MyCustomTransformFilter ---> Video Rendrer Filter
```

**ii) In order to use GMFBridge i divede my single graph into two separate graph**

```
 First Graph  :  SourceFilter ---> MyCustomTransformFilter --> GMFBridgeSinkFilter
 Second Graph :  GMFBridgeSourceFilter ---> Video Renderer Filter
```

**Well, GMFBridgeSinkFilter and  GMFBridgeSourceFilter ? what are they? their class type?**

iii) **Then i create an intance of  IGMFBridgeControllerPtr     and make necessary init...**

```
IGMFBridgeControllerPtr bridgeController = ......

.....
bridgeController->AddStream(true, eUncompressed, true); 
bridgeController->AddStream(false, eUncompressed, true);
```

iv) **Bridge Controller add a sink filter to the source graph and connect it:**

```
 bridgeController->InsertSinkFilter(sourceGraph, sourceGraphSinkFilter);
```

**What are  sourceGraph, sourceGraphSinkFilter s ?**

```
// now connect it like this:
// SourceFilter ---> MyCustomTransformFilter ---> SourceGraphSinkFilter
```

**You mean programtically connect those filters in the source graph?**

iv) In the second graph let the controller add a source filter, and connect it to the renderer:

```
bridgeController->InsertSourceFilter(sinkFilter, renderGraph, renderGraphSourceFilter);
```

**Again what are sinkFilter,renderGraphSourceFilter etc?**

```
 // now connect it like this:
 // RenderGraphSourceFilter ---> Video Renderer Filter
```

And  **You mean programtically connect those filters in the source graph?**

Comment: I guess that you'll have two graphs, and use GMFBridge to pass data from one to another...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to create the following two graphs:

```
1: SourceFilter ---> MyCustomTransformFilter ---> GMFBridgeSinkFilter

2: GMFBridgeSourceFilter ---> Video Renderer Filter
```

Basically you do the following:

Create a GMFBridgeController and configure it, for example one video and one audio stream:

```
IGMFBridgeControllerPtr  m_pController; 
HRESULT hr = m_pController.CreateInstance(__uuidof(GMFBridgeController)); 
m_pController->AddStream(true, eUncompressed, true); 
m_pController->AddStream(false, eUncompressed, true);
```

Now let the controller add a sink filter to the source graph and connect it:

```
hr = m_pController->InsertSinkFilter(m_pSourceGraph, &m_pSourceGraphSinkFilter);
// now connect it like this:
// SourceFilter ---> MyCustomTransformFilter ---> SourceGraphSinkFilter
```

In your second graph let the controller add a source filter, and connect it to the renderer:

```
hr = m_pController->InsertSourceFilter(m_pSourceGraphSinkFilter, m_pRenderGraph, &m_pRenderGraphSourceFilter); 
// now connect it like this:
// RenderGraphSourceFilter ---> Video Renderer Filter
```

Start both graphs and connect them:

```
hr = m_pController->BridgeGraphs(m_pSourceGraphSinkFilter, m_pRenderGraphSourceFilter);
```

If you want to stop one graph, first disconnect:

```
m_pController->BridgeGraphs(NULL, NULL);
```

**edit**

Here are some clarifications you asked for:

GMFBridgeSinkFilter and  GMFBridgeSourceFilter are the filters created by GMFBridge. I don't know their exact types, but at least they derive from IBaseFilter.

m_pSourceGraph and m_pRenderGraph are the IGraphBuilder interfaces of both graphs you have created.

m_pSourceGraphSinkFilter and m_pRenderGraphSourceFilter are pointers to IBaseFilter to receive the pointer to the filter created by GMFBridge.

And yes, when I say connect filters, I mean programtically connect them. As far as I know you cannot test GMFBridge in graphedit.

Comment: Thanks Wimmel. I just confused with the variables u used.I make my points at Update part of my guestions.

Comment: @setiGuy I have added some clarification.

Comment: Thnask for clarification... Just one more question...To connect RenderGraphSourceFilter and  SourceGraphSinkFilter to my other filters i should know their pin names... What are their pin names? Or any other smart way to connect them programtically? @Wimmel

Comment: @setiGuy, there are different ways to connect those filters, I never use the pin name. See for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387915(v=vs.85).aspx, but you can also use "Render". But as this is a different topic, please ask a new quesion if it is not clear yet.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your brief answer.Best Wishes